# Struggling with setting JAVA_HOME environment variable. I am trying to install latest version of maven on mac

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

First of all, this is the vaguest download description I have ever received, [here](https://maven.apache.org/install.html#unix-based-operating-system-linux-solaris-and-mac-os-x-tips).

I don't know how to set my JAVA_HOME environment variable. When using `echo $JAVA_HOME` it gives me nothing at all, like the command line just returns an empty line. I am using OS X Catalina at the moment, I have JDK 13 installed properly.

I have check my path for where java is installed: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

I have also looked up how to set the environment variable and most tutorials only provide a way to set the path temporarily or their method of adding the `PATH=/.../13.0.2.jdk` to `.profile` does not work.

I have tried setting my path via `nano .profile` and adding various snippets along the lines of `PATH=/.../maven-3.6.3/bin`. It does not matter what I do it refuses to work with me.

I have tried other OS X tutorials on google but they are not working for me.

Please rescue me.

Comment: First what have you expected? If you don't know how to set an environment variable you should read how to do that... Where have you installed your JDK? which path?

Comment: I'm not a Mac user so I may be way off base, but... On Linux, I can run Maven using a specific Java installation by doing `JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jvm mvn ...`. I _think_ this also works on OS/X. It isn't a permanent solution, but I run Maven this way because I have a number of different JVMs install. If you can run `java` at a prompt and get the JVM launched, then Maven shouldn't actually need `JAVA_HOME` set, because it will work it out from the path to the Java binary. So setting `$PATH` to include your JVM might be an alternative to setting `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @KevinBoone So I just got it working by setting my JAVA_HOME. The only way I got it to work is by settting my JAVA_HOME and maven directory path in .bash_profile and then running source .bash_profile. The problem is I have to run ```source .bash_profile ``` every session(this is to use maven). Which isn't a major problem but still somewhat annoying.

Comment: Does the OS/X `bash` respect `$HOME/.bashrc` ?

Comment: @KevinBoone maybe, but probably not since OS/X switched from a bash shell to a ```zsh``` one, very similar but a lot of bash files I believe were deprecated. I had to recover the ```.bash_profile``` to edit it in the first place since ```.profile``` was not working for the ```PATH``` at all. Although, ```$HOME/.bashrc``` does show the path when I use echo.

Comment: Fair enough. I probably shouldn't comment, since I don't use OS/X; I just thought that the shell probably did have some mechanism to update its environment at a more opportune time, even though I don't know what it is in your case.